# php nusoap server returning cURL ERROR:56: SSL read error:00000000: lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 54

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap, nusoap

I have a SOAP Server and SOAP client both based on nusoap. The server responds fine for some of the function calls from the client but it throws an Application Error at one the function call. The error that I am getting is

**Application Error SOAP method invocation (verifyT) failed: HTTP Error: cURL ERROR:: 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 54
url: https://www.blablabla.com/bla.php?wsdl
content_type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
http_code: 401
header_size: 504
request_size: 2196
filetime: -1
ssl_verify_result: 19
redirect_count: 1....................**

I am not sure what could be the issue here. For every SOAP Server function, I am catching any exception (including PHP Exceptions) and returning according to the register on the SOAP Server.

Have been stuck in this problem for more than a week now. Not sure what to do

The client code is something like:

```
$client = new nusoap_client("https://blabalbla.com/ws/index.php?wsdl");     
$client->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1200);
$client->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) 
    throw new Exception("Failed to initialise nusoap client"); 


$wsResult = $client->call('bla_function', $data);

$soapError = $client->getError();
if (!empty($soapError))
throw new Exception("SOAP method invocation (verifyT) failed:".$soapError);

if ($client->fault)
{
   throw new Exception("{$client->faultcode}: {$client->faultdetail} ");
}       
return $wsResult;
```

Comment: You should post the code that is calling the SOAP service.

Comment: I have found the problem. What actually was happening was the server script was taking long time to execute and there was a time limitation on the client side. So the client was thinking that the server is timing out after 600 second.